# Treat any file like a bit stream for encryption/decryption

Tags: c++, encryption, file-io

This *should* be a simple enough task, but I haven't been able to figure it out, as I've been away from C++ awhile.

I have an encryption algorithm I want to test on an audio file. I want to separate this file into chunks, each the size of a C++ int. I then want to pass these values through the algorithm and funnel them into a new, encrypted file. I then need to reverse the process to demonstrate that it can be decrypted, preferably to a playable audio file.

I know how to handle the algorithm itself; it's getting the data into int-sized chunks that's the problem. How would I go about doing this, regardless of file type or format, and only read to the end of the file? It is imperative that I am also able to see how much more data is needed to fill the last int so that I can store that with the encryption scheme for reversing the process later.

Is this as simple as opening a binary input and reading ints until end of file, even if the data in the file isn't numeric?

Just to clarify, I want to treat the data as if it were numeric, not matter what kind of file I'm looking at. Basically, I want to be able to enter a file name of any format and get an input stream that allows me to read into ints, ignoring if the data is supposed to be numeric, alphanumeric, or any other form of computer data.

Comment: You might want to read about [`std::istream::read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) and [`std::ostream::write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write).

Comment: What will your program do if the file's length is not an even multiple of sizeof(int) ?

Comment: It zero-pads and records how many it padded by. It then encrypts this number and puts it at the end of the stream.

Comment: Why are you honing on `sizeof(int)` rather than using the actual symmetric algorithm block size (assuming you're using a block-cipher, which I may be utterly wrong about)? Further, the padding problem for symmetric block algorithms has been solved many times over, so why reinvent that wheel? And finally, what are your plans for *decrypting* a file encrypted on a 32bit `int` platform and decrypted on a 64bit `int` platform ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways this can be solved:

- One way is to get the whole file into memory, in an `int` vector. The size of the vector can be gotten by getting the size of the file, add `sizeof(int)` and then divide by `sizeof(int)`. This will make the size of the vector fit all data in the file as `int` including if the last few bytes is less than the size of an `int`.
- Another way is to read one `int` at a time as long as the file is okay. When the last read fails, you check [`std::istream::gcount`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount) if the last (failed) read managed to read *anything*.

Comment: I like this; I'll have to try my hand it before I can mark it as the answer (may take a while). Rest assured that if this works, and if it is the most efficient method (I may be running this code on smart phones), I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: Actually, the first method will overestimate the size by one if the size is a multiple of `sizeof(int)`. E.g. (12+4)/4 = 4, not 3. You should add `sizeof(int)-1`.